# Differentiating inside an integral sign

Tags: mathematics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm reading John Taylor's Classical Mechanics book and I'm at the part where he's deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Here is the part of the derivation that I didn't follow:

[image]

I don't get how he goes from 6.9 to 6.10 by partial-differentiating the term inside the integral. If this is allowed, I was probably missed my calculus class the day it was covered. Can someone tell me more about this? Which part of calculus is this from?

Comment: Be sure to check out the 'in popular culture' section of the wikipedia entry on differentiating under the integral sign for the anecdote about Feynman. Apparently, it is a long-standing problem that this powerful tool is not typically taught in introductory calculus classes.

Comment: @kleingordon interesting. It was never taught to us either, but our teacher used it to solve a sum in a beautiful manner. Fortunately, he gave  a quick intuitive explanation when he realised that none of us knew it. I guess the rule is so obvious to some that they forget to teach it.

Comment: @Manishearth, I agree that it seems like a pretty obvious thing to do (at least in the simple case when the limits aren't functions of your variable), but often enough in math doing something that seems obvious can get you into trouble, especially when you're relatively inexperienced. I think there should be a major effort to put this into the standard calc curriculum.

Comment: Well, now I know for certain that I'm not going to be a Feynmann. :(

Comment: Huh, interesting, I never realized that this was a common misunderstanding. Good question Joebevo :-)

Comment: @kleingordon When Feynman talks about "differentiating under the integral sign" he's referring to something more specific than this. He means the technique of introducing an additional parameter $\alpha$ into a definite integral such that, when evaluated with $\alpha=0$, you recover the original integral. If you then differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ you sometimes get an integral which is easier than the original integral, and you can then solve the resulting differential equation and set $\alpha=0$ to get the result of your definite integral.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Very cool, I wasn't aware of that trick. So maybe the Feynman anecdote wasn't as apropos as I thought. Nevertheless, the act of commuting the derivative operator with the integral is something that is not often discussed in introductory calculus classes, and I still think it should be addressed more explicitly, even if it's not as fancy as what Feynman was up to (they should probably teach that, too, but we've got to walk before we fly).

Answer (score 6):

It's known as the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). As long as $\alpha$ is not the variable being integrated over, then $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}\int f(x,\alpha) \mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\partial f(x,\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}\mathrm{d}x$$

$x$  will not be present outside the integral anyways (due to limits of the integral). As it is, while differentiating wrt $\alpha$, $x$ is constant. So it becomes a partial derivative inside.

You may want to check out the proof and more complicated forms (involving limits as functions of $\alpha$) on the linked wiki page.

Comment: It's not that intuitive to me, but I can see that it works by plugging in simple functions. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, I hated it too at first :)